How to apply a thermistor to my LED driver (TLC59116 PW package)
I currently use a TLC 59116 16-channel I2C LED driver in a 4 x 4 LED array driven by Arduino and would like to add a thermistor to the circuit design. I'm unsure where to add it or what supporting components may be needed. My design is size-constrained so I'm also trying to avoid using new components.
Please let me know how to add this component to my design, it is very much appreciated!


what is the purpose of the thermistor?

Assuming you wish to augment the internal overtemperature protection in U18, and since you are using an I2C peripheral, it would perhaps be more expedient to employ an I2C digital output temperature sensor rather than having to run additional wires back to an ADC or add a  separate ADC chip to your board.
There are various options available, I'll suggest just one, the MCP9808 which is available in a 2 x 3mm package. You should probably do a lot more than that (determining requirements for accuracy, data rate etc. and shopping around). Placing the sensor near the thermal pad copper pour on the VQFN-32 package should give decent results.
Other than perhaps a bypass capacitor there are no other components required, though it's possible that the LED multiplexing may create some noise in the temperature reading.
